# An alternative to inserting multiple vaules into a single field, when the number of values is unknown

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an idea for a table (that will contain an average of 100,000 rows, though these are constantly changing) where the fields in one column would contain multiple values (i.e. thousands, but the exact number is not known and varies).  However I read that this should be avoided (there was no reason given), so the other option was to have a child column/nested table, however I read that this should be avoiding for performance reasons.  So I considered creating another table and referring to that, however this would result in the creation of thousands of tables, obviously not the solution.
So I ask is there another solution to this?

N.B.

- As I am dealing with such large volumes of data speed is an important factor.
- Even if the multiple values were put into another table under one column, there would be an unknown and constantly varying number of columns in that table that would be associated with that data.

If this is too vague and more details are required please let me know.

@Chris Barcroft: sorry about the formatting in my comment, second time lucky:

```
ID       Parent ID    Dest Port
a           1000          41
b           1000          42
c           1000       43000
d              2          80
e              3       43000
```

Comment: as strawberry said you should not ever store multiple values in one row/col... you should have a unique id for each value.. whether that takes multiple tables or not. its better and more maintainable

Comment: 100,000 rows is not a large amount of data, unless each row has a hundreds or thousands of values.  Another table to store the lists is the best way to go.

Comment: If you have a column with some big giant list with potentially thousands of values, do you need to be able to separate them?

Comment: (I didn't quite say that - but sage advice anyway)

Comment: @Strawberry you basically did when you said see normalization.. I was just elaborating :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  @JohnRuddell the link below is where I read about the number of tables...as mine would also (like his) be a number in the thousands, I thought it to be a bad idea (in my case)

[http://serverfault.com/questions/132722/how-many-tables-can-an-ms-sql-database-hold]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More details would certainly be helpful, but based on what you've described, I think I would do this with two tables: the first table represents whatever this parent entity is, and its structure doesn't really matter.  The second would represent all these random values, and would have four columns:

```
id 
parent_id
attribute_name
attribute_value
```

Then you can have any number of these attributes associated to the parent entity.  Does that give you what you're looking for?

Comment: It does help thank you.  I'm basically linking port numbers to the source/destination IP address E.g. a packet from a source IP going to the destination can be sent from ~65000 different ports. So I'm recording each of these different source/dest ports used in communication between any source and its associating destination.

But here I would be left with duplicate values for the destination, e.g

`ID  parent ID destination port
 a   1000          41
 b   1000          42
 c   1000       43000
 e      2          80
 f      3       43000`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting (re-fomatted with the posted question)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand the issue - is it a problem for two different rows to have the same destination port?

Comment: It's not a problem.  I just thought that there would be an excessive repetition of the same destination ports, but that's just me trying to get my head around this/normalisation...where in this circumstance it’s just an inevitability.  Many thanks for your help.